# How to publish two odoo instances with nginx using, different paths instead of different server names or ports?

Tags: nginx, odoo

I would like to publish two odoo instances using different paths, like mysite.com/odoo11 and mysite.com/odoo12. I am using odoo docker images and nginx:1.15.12-alpine docker image.

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name mysite.com;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        root /var/www/html;

#   ...ssl config...


#    location / {
#        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
#        proxy_set_header Host $host;
#        proxy_pass http://odoo:8069;
#    }


    location /odoo {
        rewrite ^/odoo(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://odoo:8069;
    }

    location ~* /web/static/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://odoo:8069;

    }

}
```

I started with just one odoo instance behind /odoo path. I have been looking around and found out that the way to do it is using the rewrite rule.

```
    location /odoo {
        rewrite ^/odoo(.*) /$1 break;
```

But when I use it in my config it does not redirect to the odoo docker image, it redirects to root folder instead. This is nginx log.

```
152.206.199.193 - - [03/Oct/2020:16:20:49 +0000] "GET /odoo HTTP/2.0" 200 84 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/10/03 16:20:49 [error] 14#14: *6 open() "/var/www/html/web" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 152.206.199.193, server: example.com, request: "GET /web HTTP/2.0", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/odoo"
152.206.199.193 - - [03/Oct/2020:16:20:49 +0000] "GET /web HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://example.com/odoo" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/10/03 16:20:49 [error] 14#14: *6 open() "/var/www/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 152.206.199.193, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/web"
```

I have tried **proxy_redirect http://$host http://odoo:8069;** instead of **proxy_pass** and changing the order of the rewrite rule. I still don't get the difference between the rewrite rule and proxy_redirect or proxy_pass so it would be nice to get some insight on that as well.

This is my first question on stackoverflow so thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be successful at this.

The web page controllers, responsible to render wen pages, work based on a match with the URL path.

For example, `mysite.com/web` uses path /web`for the webclient controller. Rewriting it to`mysite.com/odoo12/web`uses path`/odoo12/web`, and this won't trigger the webclient rendering controller.

Your best option is to use subdomains instead, such as `odoo11.mysite.com` and `odoo12.mysite.com`.

Odoo even has support for this. The `dbfilter` server option can dynamically filter the database to use to the one matching the subdomain name. See: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/setup/deploy.html#dbfilter

Comment: Rigth now I can't modify DNS records so that will be the solution in the future. I thought using nginx rules I  could strip the path and then redirect to the proper docker container.  I guess I'll have to use ports then. Thanks for your answer and the tip on `dbfilter` I  will definitely use it.